# How would I show $U(3)×U(5)\cong U(15)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I want to show that
$$U(3)×U(5)\cong U(15)$$
Would I simply have to find an isomorphic map that maps the two groups, or is there a clever way to approach this? I have been trying to find an isomorphic map but have had no luck. Does anyone know of an isomorphic map that maps these two groups?

$U(3) \times U(5) = \left \{ (1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(2,4)\right \} $
and $U(15) = \left \{ 1,2,4,7,8,11,13,14\right \}$

Comment: May I know what do you mean by $U(3)$?

Comment: @AlanWang $U(n)=(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times$

Comment: Use the isomorphism $\Bbb Z/15\Bbb Z\cong\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z$ OP.

Comment: I have added the definitions of the groups in my question.

Comment: Also, $U(3) = \left \{ 1,2 \right \}$ and $U(5) = \left \{ 1,2,3,4 \right \}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elements of order 2 in $U(3)×U(5)$ are $(2,1)$, $(1,4)$ and $(2,4)$. These should map to elements of order 2 in $U(15)$: 4, 11 and 14. We can have for example
$$(1,1)\mapsto1$$
$$(2,1)\mapsto11$$
$$(1,4)\mapsto4$$
$$(2,4)\mapsto14$$
and these elements form a Klein-four subgroup of both groups. The other four elements have order 4, and we can have for example
$$(1,2)\mapsto2$$
$$(2,2)\mapsto7$$
$$(1,3)\mapsto8$$
$$(2,3)\mapsto13$$
which gives an isomorphism between $U(3)×U(5)$ and $U(15)$ as
$$\begin{array}{c|cccc}
(a,b)&1&2&4&3\\
\hline
1&1&2&4&8\\
2&11&7&14&13
\end{array}$$

- Multiplication by 2 in $U(3)$ corresponds to multiplication by 11 in $U(15)$.
- Multiplication by 2 in $U(5)$ corresponds to multiplication by 2 in $U(15)$.

Comment: This deserves a positive up-vote.

Comment: Thank you for the well detailed response, but I do not understand the last two bullets.  Additionally, what map function did you use to map elements of $U(3) \times U(5)$ to $U(15)$?

Comment: @MomoTheSir The mapping is given explicitly in the answer; I just assigned mappings based on _the order of the elements_. The last two bullets tell you that (for example) if $(a,b)$ is in $U(3)×U(5)$ and it maps to $c$ in $U(15)$, then $(2a,b)$ maps to $11c$.

Comment: Because there are 3 elements of order 2 in both groups can I just map any of the 3 elements of order 2 in $U(3) \times U(5)$ to any of the 3 elements of order 2 in $U(15)$?

Comment: @MomoTheSir The mapping is not arbitrary. All order-4 elements $a$ in $U(15)$ and $U(3)×U(5)$ have $a^2=4$, so $(1,4)\mapsto4$ is forced. There is a choice in assigning $(2,1)$ and $(2,4)$ to 11 and 14; after this, assigning any remaining element to $(1,2)$ fixes everything.

Comment: How did you determine that $(2,1) \rightarrow 11$ and $(2,4) \rightarrow 14$?  Does it matter if I assign $(2,1) \rightarrow 14$ and $(2,4) \rightarrow 11$ instead?

Comment: @MomoTheSir Doesn't matter whether $(2,1)$ maps to 11 or 14.

Answer (score 2):

This is an application of the chinese remainder theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem

If you can't come up with the map yourself, look at the map in the proof of CRT and try to prove it is an isomorphism yourself.